# Why am we still getting "Provided host key does not match remote server's fingerprint." in Netsuite when the host key sent matches that of the host?

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp, ssh-keys

We are encountering an error in Netsuite where despite the host key being inputted in Netsuite matching that of the server we're connecting to, Netsuite continues to error that the:

> "Provided host key does not match remote server's fingerprint."

Error log message in Netsuite:
[image]

On reading a similar post on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57021115/117259), and despite having already compared and matching the public key we are sending with that of the output of `ssh-keyscan server-name`, we continue to get the error.

Result from ssh-keyscan:

> [image]

Configuration being sent from Netsuite:

> [image]

We've also cleared out all other public keys from all other profiles just in case `ssh-keyscan` is reading through other profile's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` files.

As an additional note:

1. When using FileZilla, we can connect without issue using the same key pair.
2. We also spun up a temporary Windows server, installed an SFTP server on it and Netsuite managed to connect successfully using the same key pair.

Any suggestions on how we can resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

### A host key is not the same thing as the SSH public key.

#### A host key is the unique identifier for that server and only is used for server verification and not user authentication via public key stored in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

I am not familiar with NetSuite, but the thing is the terminology “host key” to me is *not* an SSH key but rather the known hosts key that one gets, for example, when one SSH’s into a server for the first time.

Reading the [info on this blog](https://blog.prolecto.com/2018/10/06/overcome-netsuite-sftp-programming-challenges/) seems to confirm that.

> #### What is NetSuite N/sftp hostKey parameter?
>
> According to the NS documentation:
>
> > An SFTP server identifies itself using a host key when a client attempts to establish a connection. Host keys are unique keys that the underlying SSH protocol uses to allow the server to provide a fingerprint. Clients can verify that the expected server has responded to the connection request for a particular URL and port number.
>
> Here is what this means. The remote server identifies itself with its hostkey when connecting to it, but NetSuite wants you to provide that value in advance in order to verify this connection. And NetSuite intentionally doesn’t provide a way for you to “request” the host key from the remote server. Instead, it wants you to “look it up manually” by using the ssh-keyscan utility (built into Windows command shell, for example).
>
> > Example: `ssh-keyscan -t rsa -p 1234 acme.com`
>
> This example will obtain (and show you) the RSA host key for acme.com when connecting on port 1234. Once you get this value, you can use it when establishing a connection using NetSuite’s “sftp.createConnection” call.

And since your server will be using SSH for SFTP, the command would look something like this:

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa -p 22 example.com
```

With port 22 being what is used for SSH connections which is what SFTP connections are anyway.